# How can I get the current time in milliseconds?

Tags: rust

How can I get the current time in milliseconds like I can in Java?

```java
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Answer (score 244):

Since Rust 1.8, you do not need to use a crate. Instead, you can use [`SystemTime`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html) and [`UNIX_EPOCH`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/constant.UNIX_EPOCH.html):

```
use std::time::{SystemTime, UNIX_EPOCH};

fn main() {
    let start = SystemTime::now();
    let since_the_epoch = start
        .duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH)
        .expect("Time went backwards");
    println!("{:?}", since_the_epoch);
}
```

If you need exactly milliseconds, you can convert the [`Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html).

#### Rust 1.33

```
let in_ms = since_the_epoch.as_millis();
```

#### Rust 1.27

```
let in_ms = since_the_epoch.as_secs() as u128 * 1000 + 
            since_the_epoch.subsec_millis() as u128;
```

#### Rust 1.8

```
let in_ms = since_the_epoch.as_secs() * 1000 +
            since_the_epoch.subsec_nanos() as u64 / 1_000_000;
```

Comment: Why systemtime rather than instant?

Comment: @AndyHayden you may wish to re-read the [documentation for `Instant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html): *There is no method to get "the number of seconds" from an instant. Instead, it only allows measuring the duration between two instants (or comparing two instants).*

Comment: Does this get seconds since Epoch, in UTC time, or would you still need to add/subtract the timezone to get an "absolute" time?

Comment: Ah according to the docs `UNIX_EPOCH` is 1970.000, UTC. So I think you don't need to consider the timezone.

Comment: is there a 64bit version or do we have to cast?

Comment: @Dominic [How do I convert between numeric types safely and idiomatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28273169/155423). Presumably durations can represent a longer span of time than 64-bits would allow.

Comment: Seems quite extreme though since I don’t think my program needs to live beyond the year 229 billion 

Comment: Just started with Rust, and it would be kind if you could share some more experience. Does everybody needs to create own function which return _current_ timestamp, or do developers _repeat themselves_ each place where the timestamp is needed. Or is it such a rare need to have a current timestamp so that it's a fine approach to compare with epoch (and handle error)?

Comment: @SergeyKaunov I'd expect that most people create a function, yes, but the important thing is likely *how* the error is handled. Some people may prefer a default value, some will raise a `panic!`, and others may propagate the error. There's no one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: Yeah, of course. I'm not bragging just try to internalize this approach which alienating at first sight: it takes so much just to have a current timestamp as a number. \
\
It's totally cute that it's possible to fine tune details, but overwhelms when there's no need for them... Sorry, I'm just on the learning curve. =))

Answer (score 62):

If you just want to do simple timings with the milliseconds, you can use [`std::time::Instant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html) like this:

```
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let start = Instant::now();

    // do stuff

    let elapsed = start.elapsed();

    // Debug format
    println!("Debug: {:?}", elapsed); 

    // Format as milliseconds rounded down
    // Since Rust 1.33:
    println!("Millis: {} ms", elapsed.as_millis());

    // Before Rust 1.33:
    println!("Millis: {} ms",
             (elapsed.as_secs() * 1_000) + (elapsed.subsec_nanos() / 1_000_000) as u64);
}
```

Output:

```
Debug: 10.93993ms
Millis: 10 ms
Millis: 10 ms
```

Comment: Also see [RFC issue 1545](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1545) for adding `as_millis` to `Duration`.

Comment: You may want to checkout https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.8.0/std/time/struct.Instant.html#method.duration_since if you want duration.

Comment: Caused `u128 is not supported`.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [time crate](https://crates.io/crates/time):

```
extern crate time;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", time::now());
}
```

It returns a [`Tm`](https://docs.rs/time/0.1.41/time/struct.Tm.html) which you can get whatever precision you want.

Comment: The `precise_time_...` functions from that crate are also relevant, if one just wishes to measure relative times.

Comment: how do I get milliseconds?

Comment: You have to use `time::now_utc()` or `time::get_time()` since Java's System.currentTimeMillis() returns UTC time. I would write `let timespec = time::get_time(); let mills = timespec.sec + timespec.nsec as i64 / 1000 / 1000;`

Comment: time::precise_time_ns()  and time::precise_time_s()

Comment: This crate is now deprecated. Use `chrono` crate instead.

Comment: The deprecation message is in the notes, but not the `readme` in case that confused anyone else:
https://docs.rs/crate/time/0.1.42

Comment: I love how in every single programming language libs related to time are constantly being deprecated.

Answer (score 22):

I've found a clear solution with [chrono](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono) in [coinnect](https://github.com/hugues31/coinnect/blob/master/src/helpers/mod.rs):

```
use chrono::prelude::*;

pub fn get_unix_timestamp_ms() -> i64 {
    let now = Utc::now();
    now.timestamp_millis()
}

pub fn get_unix_timestamp_us() -> i64 {
    let now = Utc::now();
    now.timestamp_nanos()
}
```

Answer (score 12):

As @Shepmaster mentioned, this is the equivalent of Java's `System.currentTimeMillis()` in Rust.

```rust
use std::time::{SystemTime, UNIX_EPOCH};

fn get_epoch_ms() -> u128 {
    SystemTime::now()
        .duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH)
        .unwrap()
        .as_millis()
}
```

Comment: If you want more precision, this seems to work (returning fractional milliseconds): `SystemTime::now().duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH).unwrap().as_secs_f64() * 1000f64`

Answer (score 7):

```
extern crate time;

fn timestamp() -> f64 {
    let timespec = time::get_time();
    // 1459440009.113178
    let mills: f64 = timespec.sec as f64 + (timespec.nsec as f64 / 1000.0 / 1000.0 / 1000.0);
    mills
}

fn main() {
    let ts = timestamp();
    println!("Time Stamp: {:?}", ts);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c047b64111280878ba5f674024374278&version=stable)

Comment: This doesn't return the same value as System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: True, it does return the time in seconds. In order to get the millis, you have to multiply sec by 1000 and divide nsec by 1000 less (as other answers correctly do).

Comment: @contradictioned https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c047b64111280878ba5f674024374278&version=stable

Answer (score 5):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` in Java returns the difference in milliseconds between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970.

In Rust we have `time::get_time()` which returns a [`Timespec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/time/time/struct.Timespec.html) with the current time as seconds and the offset in nanoseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970.

Example (using Rust 1.13):

```
extern crate time; //Time library

fn main() {
    //Get current time
    let current_time = time::get_time();

    //Print results
    println!("Time in seconds {}\nOffset in nanoseconds {}",
             current_time.sec, 
             current_time.nsec);

    //Calculate milliseconds
    let milliseconds = (current_time.sec as i64 * 1000) + 
                       (current_time.nsec as i64 / 1000 / 1000);

    println!("System.currentTimeMillis(): {}", milliseconds);
}
```

Reference: [Time crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/time/time/index.html), [System.currentTimeMillis()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())

Comment: The link to the crate isn't valid.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a simple one-liner that yields a `u128`, which is pretty close to what a java `long` is.

```
let timestamp = std::time::UNIX_EPOCH.elapsed().unwrap().as_millis()
```

The docs do warn about clock drifting related to SystemTime objects, but I think this does not apply here, given we're checking against a point in time way back.