# How do I convert between numeric types safely and idiomatically?

Tags: casting, rust, numbers

> Editor's note: This question is from a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and references some items that are not present in Rust 1.0. The answers still contain valuable information.

What's the idiomatic way to convert from (say) a `usize` to a `u32`?

For example, casting using `4294967295us as u32` works and the [Rust 0.12 reference docs on type casting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/reference.html#type-cast-expressions) say

> A numeric value can be cast to any numeric type. A raw pointer value can be cast to or from any integral type or raw pointer type. Any other cast is unsupported and will fail to compile.

but `4294967296us as u32` will silently overflow and give a result of 0.

I found [`ToPrimitive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/num/trait.ToPrimitive.html) and [`FromPrimitive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/num/trait.FromPrimitive.html) which provide nice functions like `to_u32() -> Option<u32>`, but they're marked as unstable:

> `#[unstable(feature = "core", reason = "trait is likely to be removed")]`

What's the idiomatic (and safe) way to convert between numeric (and pointer) types?

The platform-dependent size of `isize` / `usize` is one reason why I'm asking this question - the original scenario was I wanted to convert from `u32` to `usize` so I could represent a tree in a `Vec<u32>` (e.g. `let t = Vec![0u32, 0u32, 1u32]`, then to get the grand-parent of node 2 would be `t[t[2us] as usize]`), and I wondered how it would fail if `usize` was less than 32 bits.

Comment: Be careful using `isize` / `usize` - the range of numbers they can represent [changes based on the platform](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/usize/index.html) you are compiling for! Your example might be better expressed using `u64` instead.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

## Converting values

### From a type that fits completely within another

There's no problem here. Use the [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) trait to be explicit that there's no loss occurring:

```
fn example(v: i8) -> i32 {
    i32::from(v) // or v.into()
}
```

You could choose to use `as`, but it's recommended to avoid it when you don't need it (see below):

```
fn example(v: i8) -> i32 {
    v as i32
}
```

### From a type that doesn't fit completely in another

There isn't a single method that makes general sense - you are asking how to fit two things in a space meant for one. One good initial attempt is to use an `Option` — `Some` when the value fits and `None` otherwise. You can then fail your program or substitute a default value, depending on your needs.

Since Rust 1.34, you can use [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html):

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

fn example(v: i32) -> Option<i8> {
    i8::try_from(v).ok()
}
```

Before that, you'd have to write similar code yourself:

```
fn example(v: i32) -> Option<i8> {
    if v > std::i8::MAX as i32 {
        None
    } else {
        Some(v as i8)
    }
}
```

## From a type that may or may not fit completely within another

The range of numbers `isize` / `usize` can represent [changes based on the platform](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/usize/index.html) you are compiling for. You'll need to use `TryFrom` regardless of your *current* platform.

See also:

- [How do I convert a usize to a u32 using TryFrom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50437732/155423)
- [Why is type conversion from u64 to usize allowed using `as` but not `From`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47786322/155423)

## What `as` does

> but `4294967296us as u32` will silently overflow and give a result of 0

When converting to a smaller type, `as` just takes the lower bits of the number, disregarding the upper bits, including the sign:

```
fn main() {
    let a: u16 = 0x1234;
    let b: u8 = a as u8;
    println!("0x{:04x}, 0x{:02x}", a, b); // 0x1234, 0x34

    let a: i16 = -257;
    let b: u8 = a as u8;
    println!("0x{:02x}, 0x{:02x}", a, b); // 0xfeff, 0xff
}
```

See also:

- [What is the difference between From::from and as in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48795329/155423)

## About `ToPrimitive` / `FromPrimitive`

[RFC 369, Num Reform, states](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/621fcafd533d3d823727dd7f6e3d2a17286f34df/text/0369-num-reform.md#fromprimitive-and-friends):

> Ideally [...] `ToPrimitive` [...] would all be removed in favor of a more principled way of working with C-like enums

In the meantime, these traits live on in the [num crate](https://crates.io/crates/num):

- [`ToPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.1/num/trait.ToPrimitive.html)
- [`FromPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.1/num/trait.FromPrimitive.html)

Comment: Re how to fit 2 things in a space meant for 1: exactly, hence an API that returns an `Option<u32>` seems like exactly what I want - is there no replacement for `ToPrimitive`? That's the type of answer I was expecting (though your snippet is also useful).

Comment: @Caspar I can't point to a straight replacement, but did amend my answer to include some more pointers about what to do.

Comment: @Caspar I needed the same and packaged into an own crate: https://crates.io/crates/as_num

Comment: I thought `as` panics in debug mode, and only silently overflows in release mode?

Comment: @HutchMoore `as` never panics, AFAIK. Only mathematical operations (e.g. addition, subtraction) panic. While usually thought of as debug/release, it's separately controllable. See [How to compile and run an optimized Rust program with overflow checking enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34054669/155423)

Comment: Example of where using as can go wrong... `println!("{}", (-1i32) as u32)` will output `4294967196` with no error

Comment: How do I convert usize and isize into u64? From does not seem to work for me or am I just dumb?

Comment: @VítSkalický [How to idiomatically convert between u32 and usize?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43704758/155423). `From` / `Into` don't work because `usize` changes size depending on what platform you are building for ([Why is type conversion from u64 to usize allowed using `as` but not `From`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47786322/155423)).