# What is the difference between casting to `i32` from `usize` versus the other way?

Tags: rust

I am making a function that makes a array of size n random numbers but my comparison for the while throws an error.

```
while ar.len() as i32 < size { }
```

Complains with: expected one of `!`, `(`, `+`, `,`, `::`, `<`, or `>`, found `{`.

If I remove the `as i32` it complains with `mismatch types` and if I add a `as usize` to the size variable then it doesn't complain.

Comment: A better design would probably be to make `size` of type `usize` in the first place.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you cast from a smaller-sized type to a larger one, you won't lose any data, but the data will now take up more space.

When you cast from a larger-sized type to a smaller one, you *might* lose some of your data, but the data will take up less space.

Pretend I have a box of size **1** that can hold the numbers 0 to 9 and another box of size **2** that can hold the numbers 0 to 99.

If I want to store the number 7; both boxes will work, but I will have space left over if I use the larger box. I could move the value from the smaller box to the larger box without any trouble.

If I want to store the number 42; only one box can fit the number: the larger one. If I try to take the number and cram it in the smaller box, something will be lost, usually the upper parts of the number. In this case, my 42 would be transformed into a **2**! Oops!

In addition, signed and unsigned plays a role; when you cast between signed and unsigned numbers, you might be incorrectly interpreting the value, as a number like -1 becomes 255!

See also:

- [How do I convert between numeric types safely and idiomatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28273169/155423)

---

---

In this *particular* case, it's a bit more complicated. A `usize` is defined to be a "pointer-sized integer", which is usually the native size of the machine. On a 64-bit x64 processor, that means a `usize` is 64 bits, and on a 32-bit x86 processor, it will be 32 bits.

Casting a `usize` to a `i32` thus will operate differently depending on what type of machine you are running on.

---

The *error message* you get is because the code you've tried isn't syntactically correct, and the compiler isn't giving a good error message.

You really want to type

```
while (ar.len() as i32) < size { }
```

The parenthesis will help the precedence be properly applied.

To be on the safe side, I'd cast to the larger value:

```
while ar.len() < size as usize { }
```

See also:

- [How do I convert a usize to a u32 using TryFrom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50437732/155423)
- [How to idiomatically convert between u32 and usize?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43704758/155423)
- [Why is type conversion from u64 to usize allowed using `as` but not `From`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47786322/155423)

Comment: Just to clarify, because no one seems to have pointed this out: the problem is that the compiler *thinks* the code is introducing a parameterised type.  That is, something like `Vec<usize>`, except then it finds `{` instead of `>` and gets confused.  *Yes*, `i32` doesn't *have* any parameters, but the parser *doesn't know that.*  This is all happening before that kind of information is known.

Comment: Worth noting that if you need to cast from the larger size variable to the smaller sized variable for some reason you can instead use `try_from` like `while i32::try_from(ar.len()).unwrap() < size { }`, which will cause the code to error if it can't convert, rather than blindly slice off the extra bits. You can of course handle the error differently too, by doing something more sophisticated than an `unwrap`.

Comment: isn't `usize` is just an integer of i32 on 32bit system and i64 on 64bit system ? Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @STEEL yes, `usize` takes 16, 32 or 64 bits depending on the target platform. However, it is _not_ an alias of `u16` / `u32` / `u64`, it is a separate type. Also `usize` is unsigned while `i32` / `i64` is signed.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that your `size` is of type `i32`. You either need parentheses:

```
while (ar.len() as i32) < size { }
```

or cast `size` to `usize`:

```
while ar.len() < size as usize { }
```

as `len()` returns a `usize` and the types on both sides of the comparison need to match. You need the parentheses in the first case so that the `<` operator doesn't try to compare `i32` with `size` but rather `ar.len() as i32` with `size` which is your intention.