# How to idiomatically convert between u32 and usize?

Tags: types, rust, type-conversion

This code works and prints "b":

```
fn main() {
    let s = "abc";
    let ch = s.chars().nth(1).unwrap();
    println!("{}", ch);
}
```

On the other hand, this code results in a mismatch type error.

```
fn main() {
    let s = "abc";
    let n: u32 = 1;
    let ch = s.chars().nth(n).unwrap();
    println!("{}", ch);
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:28
  |
5 |     let ch = s.chars().nth(n).unwrap();
  |                            ^ expected usize, found u32
```

For some external reason, I have to use the `u32` type for variable `n`. How can I convert `u32` to `usize` and use it in `nth()`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `as` operator works for all number types:

```
let ch = s.chars().nth(n as usize).unwrap();
```

Rust forces you to cast integers to make sure you're aware of signedness or overflows.

Integer constants can have a type suffix:

```
let n = 1u32;
```

However, note that negative constants, such as `-1i32` is internally `-` `1i32`.

Integer variables declared without an explicit type specification are shown as `{integer}` and will be properly inferred from one of the method calls.

Comment: To protect people who blindly copy&paste this answer: I think the answer from @Shepmaster (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55769098/1290383) should be the "accepted" answer. Someone might stumble across this answer here thinking that using `as` is save for numeric casts but it's not.

Comment: casts between integertypes are safe in the sense they produve deterministic results. Tgose results may not be what you want, but the same applies to nost numeric operations.

Answer (score 77):

The most cautious thing you can do is to use [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) and panic when the value cannot fit within a `usize`:

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

fn main() {
    let s = "abc";
    let n: u32 = 1;
    let n_us = usize::try_from(n).unwrap();
    let ch = s.chars().nth(n_us).unwrap();
    println!("{}", ch);
}
```

By blindly using `as`, your code will fail in mysterious ways when run on a platform where `usize` is smaller than 32-bits. For example, some microcontrollers use 16-bit integers as the native size:

```
fn main() {
    let n: u32 = 0x1_FF_FF;
    // Pretend that `usize` is 16-bit
    let n_us: u16 = n as u16;
    
    println!("{}, {}", n, n_us); // 131071, 65535
}
```

For broader types of numeric conversion beyond `u32` <-> `usize`, refer to [How do I convert between numeric types safely and idiomatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28273169/155423).

See also:

- [Why is type conversion from u64 to usize allowed using `as` but not `From`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47786322/155423)

Comment: I think before using `TryFrom`, FOR SOME CASES, a developer could also use the `From` trait (e.g. `u32::from(n)`. This should issue an error at compile-time if the cast is not implemented in the Rust-Compiler.

HOWEVER: As far as i can see, the `From` trait for `isize` and `usize` is only implemented for u8 and u16 but are not checked depending on the platform (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/convert/num.rs.html#44 and https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/convert/num.rs.html#135). This could be an issue for 8-bit microcontrollers (not sure if Rust supports them)

Comment: @obraunsdorf linked to an existing answer that covers that, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We now have a pretty different answer when we try to compile your code, replacing the number `1` with a variable of type `i32`:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:28
  |
5 |     let ch = s.chars().nth(n).unwrap();
  |                            ^ expected usize, found i32
help: you can convert an `i32` to `usize` and panic if the converted value wouldn't fit
  |
5 |     let ch = s.chars().nth(n.try_into().unwrap()).unwrap();
  |
```

It means that now the compiler recommends you to use `n.try_into().unwrap()` that makes use of the trait [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) which in turn relies on `TryFrom` and returns a `Result<T, T::Error>`. That's why we need to extract the result with a `.unwrap()`

[`TryInto` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html)

Comment: This is effectively already covered by an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55769098/155423), as `TryFrom` / `TryInto` are mirrors of each other.