# Error trying to slice bytes expected `usize`, found `u32`

Tags: rust

Im trying to slice into a buffer but am getting an error.

```
let mut buf = Vec::new();
let mut dst = [0u8; 4];
let read_index = 0;

dst.clone_from_slice(&buf[read_index..(read_index+3)]);
let length = u32::from_be_bytes(dst);
    
&buf[(read_index+4)..(read_index+length)]
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:28:79
   |
28 |         let trade = root_as_fb_iq_feed_trade(&buf[(read_index+4)..(read_index+length)]);
   |                                                                               ^^^^^^ expected `usize`, found `u32`

error[E0277]: cannot add `u32` to `usize`
  --> src/main.rs:28:78
   |
28 |         let trade = root_as_fb_iq_feed_trade(&buf[(read_index+4)..(read_index+length)]);
   |                                                                              ^ no implementation for `usize + u32`
   |
   = help: the trait `Add<u32>` is not implemented for `usize`
```

Comment: Dose this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704758/how-to-idiomatically-convert-between-u32-and-usize

Answer (score 1):

```
let mut buf = Vec::new();
let read_index = 0;

dst.clone_from_slice(&buf[read_index..(read_index+3)]);
let length = usize::from_be_bytes(dst); // u32 -> usize
    
&buf[(read_index+4)..(read_index+length)]
```

`usize` supports the `from_be_bytes` method: [The Rust doc of size::from_be_bytes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.from_be_bytes)

The error info from the compiler is clear enough to make you write the code that works. There is also specification on the doc I mentioned above, the function `from_be_bytes` only accepts the param as `[u8; 8]`, so there is one more modification:

```
let mut buf = Vec::new();
let mut dst = [0u8; 8]; // Expand your buffer to the size of 8
let read_index = 0;

dst.clone_from_slice(&buf[read_index..(read_index+3)]);
let length = usize::from_be_bytes(dst);
    
&buf[(read_index+4)..(read_index+length)]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: let length = usize::from_be_bytes(dst);
   |                                           ^^^ expected an array with a fixed size of 8 elements, found one with 4 elements

Answer (score 0):

```
let length = u32::from_be_bytes(dst);
let length_us = usize::try_from(length).unwrap();
```

Comment: If this is a solution to your question, it would be good to add what exactly this code does to solve the problem