# Why is type conversion from u64 to usize allowed using `as` but not `From`?

Tags: rust, type-conversion, numbers

The first conversion using 'as' compiles, but the second one using the 'From' trait does not:

```
fn main() {
    let a: u64 = 5;
    let b = a as usize;
    let b = usize::from(a);
}
```

Using Rust 1.34.0, I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `usize: std::convert::From<u64>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:4:13
  |
4 |     let b = usize::from(a);
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<u64>` is not implemented for `usize`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <usize as std::convert::From<bool>>
            <usize as std::convert::From<std::num::NonZeroUsize>>
            <usize as std::convert::From<u16>>
            <usize as std::convert::From<u8>>
  = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

When I replace `u64` with `u8`, there is no more error. From the error message, I understand that the `From` trait is implemented only for `u8`, but not for the other integer types.

If there is a good reason for that, then why shouldn't the conversion using 'as' should also fail to compile?

Answer (score 26):

`as` casts are fundamentally different from `From` conversions. `From` conversions are "***simple*** and safe" whereas `as` casts are purely "safe". When considering numeric types, `From` conversions exist only when the output is guaranteed to be the *same*, i.e. there is no loss of information (no truncation or flooring or loss of precision). `as` casts, however, do not have this limitation.

Quoting the docs,

> The size of [`usize`] is "how many bytes it takes to reference any location in memory. For example, on a 32 bit target, this is 4 bytes and on a 64 bit target, this is 8 bytes."

Since the size depends on the target architecture and cannot be determined before compilation, there is no guarantee that a `From` conversion between a numeric type and `usize` is possible. An `as` cast, however, will always operate by the rules listed [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/casting-between-types.html#numeric-casts).

For instance, on a 32-bit system, `usize` is equivalent to `u32`. Since a `usize` is smaller than a `u64`, there can be loss of information (truncation) when converting a `u64` into a `usize` and hence a `From` conversion cannot exist. However, the size of a `usize` is always guaranteed to be 8 bits or greater and a `u8` to `usize` `From` conversion will always exist.

Comment: With this understanding, I tried `println!("{}", 500u16 as u8);` and get 244. I assume "safe" means here just the fact that we cannot mess with the memory, but we still might end up with a completly wrong number. Since I hesitate to call this "safe" from the math point of view, I suggest to replace "casts are purely "safe"" with "casts are only "memory safe", but might change the value" or so in your answer. This way, a future reader would have a stronger warning about potential bugs they can still create and would avoid a false sense of “safety”.

Comment: [rust reference: Unsafety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/unsafety.html): "Unsafe operations are those that potentially violate the memory-safety guarantees of Rust's static semantics."

Comment: @kazemakase thank you, that is what I want to say. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I don't like the "purely safe" distinction. I think we should simply say "integer unsafe"

Comment: I think it's worth keeping in mind that "safe" is really meant to imply "safe from (accidental or intentional) attacks.  `as` is _safe_ because it still does not allow access to any part of memory that is not intended.  I think an entirely "orthogonal" word with no similar implication, like "correct" should be used.  Using that verbiage, `From` is _safe and guaranteed correct_, whereas `as` is only safe.

Answer (score 13):

As already mentioned, converting from a 64-bit value to a `usize` might cause truncation; you might lose data when a `usize` is 16 or 32 bits.

Fallable conversions are covered by the [`TryFrom` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html), available in Rust 1.34:

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

fn main() {
    let a: u64 = 5;
    let b = a as usize;
    let b = usize::try_from(a);
}
```

See also:

- [How do I convert a usize to a u32 using TryFrom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50437732/155423)

Comment: But surprisingly you can't (currently) use `TryFrom` when going the other way: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49415