# What is the difference between From::from and as in Rust?

Tags: casting, rust

I can cast between types by using either `from` or `as`:

```
i64::from(42i32);
42i32 as i64;
```

What is the difference between those?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`as` can only be used in a small, fixed set of transformations. [The reference documents `as`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#type-cast-expressions):

> `as` can be used to explicitly perform [coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/reference/type-coercions.html), as
> well as the following additional casts. Here `*T` means either `*const T` or
> `*mut T`.
>
> | Type of `e` | `U` | Cast performed by `e as U` |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Integer or Float type | Integer or Float type | Numeric cast |
> | C-like enum | Integer type | Enum cast |
> | `bool` or `char` | Integer type | Primitive to integer cast |
> | `u8` | `char` | `u8` to `char` cast |
> | `*T` | `*V` where `V: Sized` * | Pointer to pointer cast |
> | `*T` where `T: Sized` | Numeric type | Pointer to address cast |
> | Integer type | `*V` where `V: Sized` | Address to pointer cast |
> | `&[T; n]` | `*const T` | Array to pointer cast |
> | [Function item](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/reference/types/function-item.html) | [Function pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/reference/types/function-pointer.html) | Function item to function pointer cast |
> | [Function item](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/reference/types/function-item.html) | `*V` where `V: Sized` | Function item to pointer cast |
> | [Function item](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/reference/types/function-item.html) | Integer | Function item to address cast |
> | [Function pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/reference/types/function-pointer.html) | `*V` where `V: Sized` | Function pointer to pointer cast |
> | [Function pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/reference/types/function-pointer.html) | Integer | Function pointer to address cast |
> | Closure ** | Function pointer | Closure to function pointer cast |
>
> * or `T` and `V` are compatible unsized types, e.g., both slices, both the
> same trait object.
>
> ** only for closures that do not capture (close over) any local variables

Because `as` is known to the compiler and only valid for certain transformations, it can do certain types of more complicated transformations.

[`From` is a trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html), which means that any programmer can implement it for their own types and it is thus able to be applied in more situations. It pairs with [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html). [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) and [`TryInto`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryInto.html) have been stable since Rust 1.34.

Because it's a trait, it can be used in a generic context (`fn foo(name: impl Into<String>) { /* ... */ }`). This is not possible with `as` (although see [`AsPrimitive`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/traits/trait.AsPrimitive.html) from the num crate).

When converting between numeric types, one thing to note is that `From` is only implemented for *lossless conversions* (e.g. you can convert from `i32` to `i64` with `From`, but not the other way around), whereas `as` works for both lossless and lossy conversions (if the conversion is lossy, it truncates). Thus, if you want to ensure that you don't accidentally perform a lossy conversion, you may prefer using `From::from` rather than `as`.

See also:

- [When should I implement std::convert::From vs std::convert::Into?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29812530/155423)