# How do I convert a Rust numeric type but only if it fits?

Tags: rust

I want the following

```
(2u128.pow(x)) as u64
```

but such that it succeeds for `x < 64` and fails for `x >= 64`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out yourself, you should use `TryFrom`, but you should also make sure the exponentiation itself doesn't overflow, by using [`u128::checked_pow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.checked_pow) instead of [`u128::pow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html#method.pow):

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

let x = 129;
let y = 2u128.checked_pow(x).expect("Number too big for exponentiation");
let z = u64::try_from(y).expect("Number too big for cast");
```

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=b8cb051690fb937aef13118392899561))

Comment: tbh I am kind of disappointed that pow() isn't checked. Where are the safe defaults, damnit? Thank, you! Good catch!

Comment: @Sarien Rust aims to be a performant language, and tries not to force overhead on you if you don't want it. When running in debug mode, `pow()` will panic on overflow, but in release mode it is unchecked. This isn't considered "unsafe" in the Rust sense of the word, since it can't trigger undefined behaviour. If you want the check in release mode, you can still use `checked_pow()`.

Comment: Also, all the arithmetic operations can fail for the right pair of values. If they all returned a `Result`/`Option` rather than the behavior they have now, it would be sooooo painful to use. Consider that a simple `a + b*c` would become at least `(a + (b*c)?)?`.

Comment: On the other hand, Rust also aims to be a safe language, so maybe it should either make me think about that case or just promote to BigInt if necessary. I understand the trade-off, though.

Comment: Or you could use directly `2u64.checked_pow`, no need to go through a 128 bits value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the answer, there is [TryFrom](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html).

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;

u64::try_from(2u128.pow(x)).expect("Number too big for cast.")
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273169/how-do-i-convert-between-numeric-types-safely-and-idiomatically) which I somehow missed with my first search.

Comment: How about [even bigger `x`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=3f571eba4117238a923039489c8b9964)?