# What implicit numeric conversions does Rust support?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

On page 51 of [*"Programming Rust"* by Jim Blandy & Jason Orendorff](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920040385.do) the authors state,

> Unlike C and C++, Rust performs **almost** no numeric conversions implicitly.

Why *"almost"*? What implicit numeric conversions will Rust perform?

Comment: None that come to mind. See also [How do I convert between numeric types safely and idiomatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28273169/155423). My gut says that the authors used "weasel words" because proving a negative is hard and prone to breaking if Rust ever decides to add one.

Comment: @Shepmaster I think the only fair thing, in light of how hard it is to prove a negative is to mark your comment as an answer pending someone else demonstrating otherwise.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is the way that numeric constants are handled. E.g. `let a: u8 = 1;` automatically "converts" the `1` into an `u8` ("converts" between quotes because it is not strictly speaking a conversion, but it could look that way at first glance).

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments above I don't know of any such implicit conversion and couldn't find an example, but the [Rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/) book states the following about [type casts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/types/cast.html)

> Rust provides no implicit type conversion (coercion) between primitive types. But, explicit type conversion (casting) can be performed using the `as` keyword.

There is/was a [Pre-RFC](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-implicit-number-type-widening/10432/121) where this topic got discussed in more detail showing the pro/con arguments about why Rust should/n't have this feature.

For further information you may have a look at the [From and Into](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/from_into.html) traits.