# How to implement Into trait to convert all input to usize not using `as usize`?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a function that returns the [compound duration](https://github.com/nbari/compound_duration/blob/master/src/lib.rs) based on an `usize` input:

```
pub fn format_dhms(seconds: usize) -> String
```

If the input is `6000000`:

```
println!("{}", format_dhms(6000000));
```

It returns:

```
69d10h40m
```

This works when the input is a number, but when I use the output of another function with a fixed type, I need to use `as usize`. For example, if I use the output of [`Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html) using methods `as_secs() = u64` or `as_nanos() = u128`.

When someone passes `u128::MAX`, I would like to deal with it like as `usize` does by truncating the input to the max accepted value.

This is what I am trying: (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4a8bfa152febee9abb52d8244a5092c5)

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
use std::time::Instant;

fn format<T: Into<usize>>(number: T) {
    if number == 0 {
        //println!("{}", number)
    } else {
        //println!("{}> 0", number)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let now = Instant::now();
    format(now.elapsed().as_nanos()); // u128
    format(now.elapsed().as_secs()); // u64
}
```

But some of the errors I get are:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `usize: std::convert::From<i32>` is not satisfied
    the trait `std::convert::From<i32>` is not implemented for `usize`
...
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `T`
```

If I remove the `<T: Into<size>>` it works, but I need to use `as usize`.

```
 format(now.elapsed().as_nanos() as usize);
```

Is there a way I could convert the input to prevent using the `as usize` or how to achieve same behavior when input is just a number with no defined type?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I convert between numeric types safely and idiomatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28273169/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: *`as_nanos() = u128`* — there are no systems that Rust runs on where `usize` is big enough to hold a `u128`. What do you want to happen when someone passes in `u128::MAX`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::mem::size_of` to check if the input type fits in a `usize` and use bit-manipulations to truncate when it doesn't:

```
use std::convert::{ TryFrom, TryInto };
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::ops::BitAnd;
use std::time::Instant;

fn format<T: TryInto<usize> + TryFrom<usize> + BitAnd<Output=T>> (number: T)
    where <T as TryFrom<usize>>::Error: Debug,
          <T as TryInto<usize>>::Error: Debug
{
    let number: usize = if std::mem::size_of::<T>() <= std::mem::size_of::<usize>() {
        number.try_into().unwrap()
    } else {
        (number & usize::MAX.try_into().unwrap()).try_into().unwrap()
    };
    if number == 0 {
        //println!("{}", number)
    } else {
        //println!("{}> 0", number)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4154edf6db7f76c41206f63e4ada4a9d)

Note that so long as you only use unsigned types, the `unwrap`s should never fail since the check on type sizes ensures that the conversions are always valid.

Comment: `...(number: T) where <T as TryFrom<usize>>::Error: Debug, <T as TryInto<usize>>::Error: Debug`, is there a way to prevent the `where`? only asking for learning more about other possible  alternatives

Comment: The where is required for the calls to `unwrap`. If you replace them with `unwrap_or_else (|_| unreachable!())` then [you can get rid of the `where` clauses](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f0bc050fcc189c57c104340db9d76a8)

Comment: [error: literal out of range for `i32`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=09e5b09ff9da8d207de4729381b0c712) when formatting `4_294_967_295` something that works when using `as usize`, how could "all" ranges be accepted or behave like `as usize`

Comment: I tried using `#[allow(overflowing_literals)]` but still get the error

Comment: That's a different issue: for literals (ie. numbers that are typed directly in the code), the compiler attempts to guess which type to use and falls back to `i32` if it can't. Since the function is generic the compiler can't guess, but the number doesn't fit in an `i32`. So you have to be explicit and [write `4_294_967_295usize`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=36583d836067aa13f4a42d13c0cb48d7).

Comment: Is there a way "one size fits all" approach? or probably better to just continue using `as usize` to prevent extra points of failure.

Comment: There is no way to have a generic function that will accept `4_294_967_295` without the `usize` suffix. Whether it is preferable to have a function that's easy to call in most situations or to be explicit about the conversions is something you will have to decide depending on your precise use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) trait, you can "try" to convert to a different type. Should the input number be too big for `usize`, you will get an error.

```rust
fn foo<T: TryInto<usize>>(x: T) -> usize {
    x.try_into().unwrap() // Will panic if
                          // x cannot fit
                          // into a usize.
}
```

Additionally, this does not have the same semantic effect as `as` casts. Since those will truncate, while this will just not work.

---

The real best practice in this case would be to just use regular trait bounds for numbers, instead of using `usize`, since some values don't fit in there:

```rust
fn format<
    T: Sub<Output = T> + 
       Mul<Output = T> + 
       Div<Output = T> + 
       Display + 
       PartialEq +
       From<bool>        //etc. for all the operations you need. 
    >(number: T) {
    if number == T::from(false) { // `false` turns into 0 for numbers. 
        //println!("{}", number)
    } else {
        //println!("{}> 0", number)
    }
}
```

The `std` number traits however, are rather barebones, so I'd recommend you look at [`num_traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.11/num_traits/).

Comment: you can't write number == 0 with these bounds

Comment: This doesn't meet OP's requirements — "by truncating the input to the max accepted value"

Comment: Also, this answer seems to concur that it would have been a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/28273169/155423.

Comment: @Stargateur I edited it with a workaround, however it's probably better to use num traits.