# Why does my program incorrectly calculate the MD2 hash?

Tags: hash, rust

As a learning exercise, I have attempted to implement the MD2 hashing algorithm, using only [RFC 1319](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1319) as reference:

```rust
use std::str;

const PI_SUBST: [u8; 256] = [
    41, 46, 67, 201, 162, 216, 124, 1, 61, 54, 84, 161, 236, 240, 6, 19, 98, 167, 5, 243, 192, 199,
    115, 140, 152, 147, 43, 217, 188, 76, 130, 202, 30, 155, 87, 60, 253, 212, 224, 22, 103, 66,
    111, 24, 138, 23, 229, 18, 190, 78, 196, 214, 218, 158, 222, 73, 160, 251, 245, 142, 187, 47,
    238, 122, 169, 104, 121, 145, 21, 178, 7, 63, 148, 194, 16, 137, 11, 34, 95, 33, 128, 127, 93,
    154, 90, 144, 50, 39, 53, 62, 204, 231, 191, 247, 151, 3, 255, 25, 48, 179, 72, 165, 181, 209,
    215, 94, 146, 42, 172, 86, 170, 198, 79, 184, 56, 210, 150, 164, 125, 182, 118, 252, 107, 226,
    156, 116, 4, 241, 69, 157, 112, 89, 100, 113, 135, 32, 134, 91, 207, 101, 230, 45, 168, 2, 27,
    96, 37, 173, 174, 176, 185, 246, 28, 70, 97, 105, 52, 64, 126, 15, 85, 71, 163, 35, 221, 81,
    175, 58, 195, 92, 249, 206, 186, 197, 234, 38, 44, 83, 13, 110, 133, 40, 132, 9, 211, 223, 205,
    244, 65, 129, 77, 82, 106, 220, 55, 200, 108, 193, 171, 250, 36, 225, 123, 8, 12, 189, 177, 74,
    120, 136, 149, 139, 227, 99, 232, 109, 233, 203, 213, 254, 59, 0, 29, 57, 242, 239, 183, 14,
    102, 88, 208, 228, 166, 119, 114, 248, 235, 117, 75, 10, 49, 68, 80, 180, 143, 237, 31, 26,
    219, 153, 141, 51, 159, 17, 131, 20,
];

fn main() {
    let l = pad_to_16("hello".to_string().into_bytes());
    let l = append_checksum(l);
    let l = calculate_hash(l);

    let l = format!("{:02x?}", l);
    let l = l.replace("[", "");
    let l = l.replace("]", "");
    let l = l.replace(",", "");
    let l = l.replace(" ", "");
    println!("{}", l);
}

fn pad_to_16(s: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut output_vec = s.clone();
    let s_len = s.len();
    let padding_len = 16 - (s_len % 16);

    for i in 0..padding_len {
        output_vec.push(padding_len as u8)
    }
    output_vec
}

fn append_checksum(m: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    // C[i] represents ith element of checksum
    // S[i] represents ith element of PI_SUBST
    // L represents l
    // N represents number of bytes of m

    // For i = 0 to 15 do
    //  Set C[i] to 0
    // end
    let mut checksum: Vec<u8> = vec![0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    let n = m.len();
    // Set L to 0.
    let mut l = 0;
    let mut output_vec = m.clone();

    // For i = 0 to N/16 - 1 do
    for i in 0..n / 16 {
        // For j = 0 to 15 do
        for j in 0..16 {
            // Set c to M[i*16 + j]
            let c = m[(i * 16) + j];
            // Set C[j] to S[c xor l]
            checksum[j] = PI_SUBST[(c ^ l) as usize];
            // Set L to C[j]
            l = checksum[j];
        }
    }
    output_vec.append(&mut checksum);
    output_vec
}

fn calculate_hash(m: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let mut x = vec![
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ];

    let n = m.len();
    for i in 0..n / 16 {
        for j in 0..16 {
            x[16 + j] = m[i * 16 + j];
            x[32 + j] = x[16 + j] ^ x[j];
        }

        let mut t = 0;

        for j in 0..18 {
            for k in 0..48 {
                t = (x[k] ^ PI_SUBST[t]) as usize;
                x[k] = x[k] ^ PI_SUBST[t];
            }

            t = (t + j) % 256
        }
    }

    let output = x[0..16].to_vec();
    output
}
```

According to online MD2 hashing tools, the string "hello" should produce `a9046c73e00331af68917d3804f70655`, whereas my implementation produces `fd00eb11ff9ce26868e51885a0e545c8`.

I have been unable to determine why my program is incorrectly producing the hash, as I believe I have followed the RFC pretty closely. I suspect that the issue could be due to how different values are being cast as `usize`, but I am not sure how to test this.

Comment: Regarding the casts, a skim suggests that none of them are likely to be problematic, but you can do something about them, if you're interested: **replace all uses of the `as` operator**. When going from smaller integers to larger ones, write `n.into()` or `usize::from(n)` if needed to disambiguate, and for larger numbers to smaller ones, `n.try_into().expect("this particular number was too big!")` (requires `use std::convert::TryInto;`). This ensures that every conversion either can't overflow or panics if it would overflow.

Comment: In longer form — [How do I convert between numeric types safely and idiomatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28273169/155423)

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to figure out the problem causing the incorrect calculation. It was in these two lines:

```rust
t = (x[k] ^ PI_SUBST[t]) as usize;
x[k] = x[k] ^ PI_SUBST[t];
```

In reality, these operations should be flipped. The correct code:

```rust
x[k] ^= PI_SUBST[t as usize];
t = x[k] as u32;
```

And for "hello" the new code produces `a9046c73e00331af68917d3804f70655` correctly.

Comment: I'd say that the crucial change you've made is the order of the two lines `t = …; x[k] = …;` to `x[k] = …; t = …;` rather than the casts.

Comment: Thank you, I’ve amended the answer