# Convert u64 to f64

Tags: rust, casting, numbers

Given `u64` number `u64value: u64`. How can it be lossy converted into `f64`? Will `u64value as f64` always work?

Comment: Yes, it will always work. Why not?

Comment: Because I haven't found documentation of how `as` works in this case.

Comment: Now I reached the documentation page from the answer: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#type-cast-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you explicitly stated *« lossy »*, there is no problem.
If the original `u64` value is quite big, you will lose some lower bits due to the limited precision of the `f64`.

See the reference about the [type cast expressions with `as`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#type-cast-expressions).

(see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28280042/11527076))

```rust
fn main() {
    let u64value: u64 = 123_456_789_123_456_789;
    let f64value: f64 = u64value as f64;
    let u64back: u64 = f64value as u64;
    println!("u64value: {:?}", u64value);
    println!("f64value: {:?}", f64value);
    println!("u64back: {:?}", u64back);
    println!("delta: {:?}", u64value - u64back);
}
/*
u64value: 123456789123456789
f64value: 1.2345678912345678e17
u64back: 123456789123456784
delta: 5
*/
```

Comment: You can even use `let u64value: u64 = u64::MAX` to make sure `u64` fits into `f64`.

Comment: @denis.peplin unfortunately, with `u64::MAX` nothing is lost since the obtained `f64` does not use its mantissa (except the implicit leading 1); everything is expressed in the exponent. See for example [this converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) with `f32`/`u32::MAX`(4294967295).

Comment: @prog-fh Can you add direct link to rust documentation, which explains semantics of `as` on numerics? I found it by following a link, which was mentioned in the answer you linked (too many indirections). (e.g., https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.49.0/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#type-cast-expressions)