# How do I get a Duration as a number of milliseconds in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a [`time::Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html). How can I get the number of milliseconds represented by this duration as an integer? There used to be a `num_milliseconds()` function, but it is no longer available.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, keep an eye on [this RFC issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1545) for any future RFCs regarding this.

Comment: use chrono http://exercism.io/submissions/1264089798d244e5b8278e588919901c

Comment: See also [How can I get the current time in milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26593387/155423)

Comment: As of today, I could successfully use num_milliseconds.

Answer (score 9):

Since Rust 1.33.0, there is an [`as_millis()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html#method.as_millis) function:

```
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn main() {
    let now = SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).expect("get millis error");
    println!("now millis: {}", now.as_millis());
}
```

Since Rust 1.27.0, there is a [`subsec_millis()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html#method.subsec_millis) function:

```
use std::time::SystemTime;

fn main() {
    let since_the_epoch = SystemTime::now().duration_since(SystemTime::UNIX_EPOCH).expect("get millis error");
    let seconds = since_the_epoch.as_secs();
    let subsec_millis = since_the_epoch.subsec_millis() as u64;
    println!("now millis: {}", seconds * 1000 + subsec_millis);
}
```

Since Rust 1.8, there is a [`subsec_nanos`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html#method.subsec_nanos) function:

```
let in_ms = since_the_epoch.as_secs() * 1000 +
            since_the_epoch.subsec_nanos() as u64 / 1_000_000;
```

See also:

- [How can I get the current time in milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44378174/5657884)

Comment: What does Rust 2018 have to do with the problem? Why are you using `SystemTime` instead of directly using a `Duration`?

Comment: New to Rust; what advantage do the solutions above have over the simpler: `duration.as_secs_f64() * 1000f64`? It's much more precise than `duration.as_millis()` (ie. it gives me results like `6.716969ms` rather than just an integer), while being simpler than the other two options.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution I came up with, which is to multiply the seconds by a billion, add it to the nanoseconds, then divide by 1e6.

```
let nanos = timeout_duration.subsec_nanos() as u64;
let ms = (1000*1000*1000 * timeout_duration.as_secs() + nanos)/(1000 * 1000);
```

Comment: I'd rather multiply seconds by 1000, then add `nanos/1000000`. Less risk of overflow.

Comment: `subsec_nanos` doesn't return the number of elapsed nanoseconds. It represents the precision of the Duration.

Comment: @w.brian the example in the documentation https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html#method.subsec_nanos supports the facts that the method returns the fractional part of the duration in nanoseconds, so the answer seems correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`time::Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/time/time/struct.Duration.html) from the [time crate](https://crates.io/crates/time) on crates.io which provides a `num_milliseconds()` method.